# positioning elements inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

```
<td id="name_3869-0_0" style="position: relative; " colspan="4">
    <div style="float:left;width:100%">
        <img src="/img/1.gif" align="middle" style="margin-right: 10px;" class="company_symbol" border="0">
        <strong style="margin: auto 5px auto auto; ">yyyy</strong>
        <a href="#"><span title="xxxx">xxxx</span></a>
        <span class="mm_msg_ident"><img onclick="mm_Msg.sel('[1]730228')" src="/view/new_design/img/msg_unchecked.gif" border="0" align="top" alt="Private message to the owner of subdivision" title="Private message to the owner of subdivision"></span>
        <span><a href="#" title="Cancel the contract" alt="Cancel the contract" onclick="return contractDestroy(1510428, 'xxxxx')"><img src="/img/smallX.gif" alt="Cancel the contract" border="0" align="top" style="margin-right: 1px"></a></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="supplyContractData[selected][]" value="1510428">
    </div>
</td>
```

What I need is to make sure that the two spans (one with class mm_msg_ident, and the one immediately following it)
are always positioned at the top right corner of the div. The problem is that the size of the div is variable, and
has to stay variable. I have access to jquery 1.6.4. Any suggestions on how to style these elements to accomplish that?

edit: assume the two spans in concern have size 20x20 each.

Comment: there is no need for jquery, just use `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `position: relative;` on the `<div>` and give it a class e.g. `container`

then in your css:

```
.container span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.mm_msg_ident {
    right 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey now just add one properties in you css as like this

```
.wrapper:hover .description {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

---

---

Hey now you can do this without jquery as like this

**Css**

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #0D5A2C;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
}


.description {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    left:8px;
    right:8px;
    top:8px;
    bottom:8px;
    padding: 120px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
}
.wrapper:hover .description{
display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img alt="Hamster on Swing" src="http://www.webdesignlondon-tristar.co.uk/tutorials/jquery/imagedivrollover/hamster.jpg">


<a class="description" title="Click for More" href="#">
<img alt="Search" src="http://www.webdesignlondon-tristar.co.uk/tutorials/jquery/imagedivrollover/search.png">Want to read more?
</a>


</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/svkQx/1/

---

if you now want to opacity than used to this

just replace one css in your css code

```
.description {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Live demo with opacity http://jsfiddle.net/svkQx/2/